# Can you explain this named group start position in a Java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm stuck in a weird situation here, trying to match an optional named group in a Java (8) regex.

For example, the following match happens as expected and the assertions raise no error:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("begin.+(?<middle>middle).+end");
Matcher matcher = pat.matcher("begin middle end");

assertTrue(matcher.find());
assertEquals(6, matcher.start("middle"));
assertEquals(12, matcher.end("middle"));
```

However, if I change the regex to

```
begin.+(?<middle>(middle)?).+end
```

matcher.start("middle") returns 12, as if the match is empty.

If I change the regex to

```
begin.+(?<middle>middle)?.+end
```

matcher.start("middle") returns -1, as if there's no match.

I'm wondering if it's possible to have optional named groups at all in Java.

What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with named groups.

The reason is that the `.+` right after `begin` **greedily** matches the string "`middle`". 
Your named group matches nothing (which it's explicitly allowed to).

The solution is to make the first `.+` [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), e.g.:

```
begin.+?(?<middle>(middle)?).+end
```